# No alert or log output from my Greasemonkey script?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

**Update:** The OP now confirms that the problem occurred due to Greasemonkey being disabled.

---

I am trying to make a simple Greasemonkey script, however it doesn't appear to do anything and nothing relevant appears in the console.

The script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        test
// @namespace   test
// @description testing script (jquery)
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js
// @include *
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
alert("hello");
 GM_log("hello, greasemonkey here");});
```

I have tried it without the `$(document).ready` and jquery, however it still does not work.

Comment: The script did too run. You saw the alert (unless you told FF to block alerts from the site) and the error message `GM_log is not defined` was placed in Firefox's error console.

Comment: @BrockAdams Well, not for me.. What version of FF are you using?

Comment: Pretty much all versions of FF after 4.0.  GM version 1.11-ish and later. Triple checked on the latest releases of both (FF 28.0 + GM 1.15).

Comment: @BrockAdams Those are the versions I'm using (28 and 1.15). I'll see what a fresh profile with only greasemonkey does.

Comment: I feel so stupid.. It turns out I had it disabled the whole time, but it was hard to tell with my theme.. Sorry about all the fuss :/

Comment: You had what disabled? Greasemonkey?

Comment: @BrockAdams Yes.. (so stupid) Should I delete this post?

Comment: You can flag it for deletion by a moderator. But, since it kinda has a good answer for the question as stated, the mod might not delete it.

Comment: @BrockAdams Okay. I'll leave it then, and accept the answer (at least thanks to it I learned something though this whole failure). Thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `@grant none` you cannot use any of the Greasemonkey functions such as `GM_log`, `GM_addStyle`, etc.

The reason why it fails is that using the `GM_` functions require the sandbox to be enabled -- `@grant none` disables this sandbox to allow code to run as it would on an ordinary page.

Instead of using `GM_log` ([which is deprecated](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_log)), you should use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) instead.

Note that when you're running Greasemonkey code that errors only go to the browser console (or Firebug if you've enabled chrome logging) -- you can access the browser console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> on Windows, and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Opt</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Though why isn't it working when I set the entire script (not including the header of course) to just the `alert`?

Comment: If he told FF to block alerts for that page, he needs to reset it. (Reload page, cacheless, or reset the `about:config` setting to default (depending on what OP did).)

Comment: @BrockAdams I've tested it on all sorts of sites, not a peep. I'll try resetting it in about:config.

Comment: Replace the `alert` with `console.log` and make sure it occurs before any other code but after the metadata block.

Comment: @BrockAdams I removed all the code and replaced it with `console.log("test")`, but nothing appears in the *Logging* section of the console (opened with Ctrl+Shift+J) on (re)loading a page.